# Он заволновался, а его взгляд(,) как у маленького щеночка.

Tags: пунктуация, как

Он заволновался, а его взгляд(,) как у маленького щеночка. 
Нужна ли запятая? Я не уверена точно. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здесь нужна не запятая, а тире, замещающее пропущенное "был" (без этого слова заметно рассогласование по времени с первым глаголом - просто "взгляд" воспринимается в настоящем времени), но лучше это слово в явном виде вписать (без запятой или тире).